# $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$?

Tags: real-analysis

For $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, let $f'(c)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$ exist for $c\in(a,b)$ and $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exist.

I was wondering if it is true that $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Comment: If the limit $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x) $ exists then your desired equality holds. Otherwise the question of it being true does not arise. An easy way to prove is via L'Hospital's Rule or mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No . As a counterexample take
$$f(x)=x^2\cos(\frac 1x)\; \text{ if } \; x>0$$
and $ f(0)=0$.

then

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=0=f'(0)$$

but for $ x>0 $,

$$f'(x)=2x\cos(\frac 1x)+\sin(\frac 1x)$$

and, it is known that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)\text{ does not exist}$$

because $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin(\frac 1x)=\lim_{X\to +\infty}\sin(X)$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there a condition when they are equal?

Comment: If $ \lim_{a^+}f'(x)=L $ then $ f'(a^+)=L$.